# Infinite loop in python using for statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that

```
while True:
    condition to break loop
```

will result in an infinite loop. But I want to do the same with a 'for' statement. Somebody please help me

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "do the same with a `for` loop"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use infinite iterator like [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) which yield items infinitely:

```
for i in itertools.repeat(1):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop with a self made range, eg:

```
def endless_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

for x in endless_range(0, 1, 0):
    condition to break loop
```

But why not using the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly how you want your items to repeat, you may just want the following.

```
while True:
    for value in items:
        # ...
        if condition:
            break
        # ...
    if condition:
        break
```

Comment: This is not answering the question.